# 0 Esquerda em double, c#

Tags: c#

Olá, estou fazendo o seguinte:

```
Fun_CPF = Convert.ToDouble(FuncionarioViewModel.Fun_CPF2),
```

`CPF2` É uma string que pode conter qualquer cpf, inclusive os cpf que comecem com 0, como `05669774144`, mas quando faço essa conversão, `Fun_CPF` recebe `5669774144`, o que posso fazer?

Comment: 0 É número ignorando no double,float e int. Ex.: 000001 //  1 ; 010 //10

Comment: Jeff Henrique. Para que você quer fazer isso?

Comment: @MauryDeveloper, não mude radicalmente o conteúdo dos comentários, principalmente se  alguém já marcou relevância, isso pode gerar discussão. Se precisar apague e escreva outro ou mantenha o comentário antigo e escreva um novo.

Comment: Eu queria deixa mais claro. É inútil trasforma em double,melhor deixa em string.

Comment: Eu estou transformando, pois vou enviar ao banco de dados, e lá é em string, mas não tentei enviar no formato string, vou tentar @MauryDeveloper

Comment: Jeff Henrrique: CPF, RG, Telefone, numero de casa você manda para o banco de dados como string(char ou varchar) só quantidades cardinais(pode ser contado ou fracionado) e ordinais(pode ser enumerado) você manda como numérico.

Comment: @MauryDeveloper, eu não quis lhe chamar atenção. É que eu li no meta um poste seu onde você disse que foi xingado(a) e as vezes uma mudança de conteúdo num comentário  ou resposta pode gerar uma reação impulsiva que resulta em desavença.

Comment: @AugustoVasques, no meu banco de dados, o campo é um double, então eu não consigo enviar uma string para ele

Comment: Unica solução que consigo pensar é alterar o campo no banco de dados, mas não sei se pode, é da minha empresa, vou descobrir dps

Comment: Mas o que queria mesmo era saber se eu consigo manter os 0 a esquerda em um campo double

Comment: é simples, se quer que aparece o 0 a esquerda só não converter. Para números não tem sentido zero a esquerda, que não agrega nada ao número, para ter zeros a esquerda mantenha string

Comment: Ok, vou dar a ideia na empresa, obrigado pela ajuda pessoal

Comment: Não, Maury Developer e o Ricardo Pontual já escreveram que os zeros a esquerda são ignorados. Há um consenso de que são 11 dígitos no CPF então você teria que contar quantos dígitos compõe o seu número e subtrair de 11 então você adiciona quanto zeros a esquerda quanto der essa conta